# Task 'installRelease' not found in root project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, task

Ok, I have the problem described in the title. This is my gradle file

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

        android {
            compileSdkVersion 27

            signingConfigs {
                debug {
                    keyAlias 'alias'
                    keyPassword 'larissa'
                    storeFile file('capstoneproject.jks')
                    storePassword 'larissa81'
                }
            }

            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "theo.tziomakas.news"
                minSdkVersion 21
                targetSdkVersion 27
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
            buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
        }

        dependencies {
            implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
            implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
            implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
            implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
            implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.2'
            implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
            implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
            implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
            implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
            implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
        }

        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And I have the jks file inside the app folder. Of course I created the apk file too.

[image: jks file]

So how can I fix that error?

And when I run the app I get this error.

```
 Keystore file '/Users/theodosiostziomakas/Desktop/capstone/Capstone-Udacity/app/capstoneproject.jks' not found for signing config 'debug'.
```

Thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check that your keystore file is located at `/Users/theodosiostziomakas/Desktop/capstone/Capstone-Udacity/app/` named with `capstoneproject.jks` and try to generate signed apk again if file is on other palace then change the path for keystore file on generate signed apk dialog by selecting `choose exixting Button` and Place your `.jks` file path here.